# How to do I update existing records using a conditional clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to Oracle SQL so I have a question .. I have two tables, Table A and Table B .. Now Table A and Table B have the same column names, but in table A, only one column (named 'tracker') actually has data in it .. The rest of the columns in Table A are empty ... What I need to do is update each record in Table A, so that values for other columns are copied over from Table B, with the condition that the the 'tracker' columns value from Table A is matched with the 'tracker' column in Table B ..

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

```
MERGE INTO tableA a
USING tableB b
ON (a.tracker=b.tracker)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET  
  a.column1=b.column1,
  a.column2=b.column2;
```

And if exist rows in B that does not exist in A:

```
MERGE INTO tableA a
USING tableB b
ON (a.tracker=b.tracker)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET  
  a.column1=b.column1,
  a.column2=b.column2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES
  a.tracker,a.column1,a.column2; --all columns
```

Answer (score 2):

```
create  table a (somedata varchar2(50), tracker number , constraint pk_a primary key (tracker));
create  table b (somedata varchar2(50), tracker number, constraint pk_b primary key (tracker));
/

--insert some data
insert into a (somedata, tracker)
select 'data-a-' || level, level
  from dual
  connect by level < 10;

insert into b (somedata, tracker)  
  select 'data-b-' || -level, level
  from dual
  connect by level < 10;



  select * from a;
SOMEDATA                                           TRACKER
-------------------------------------------------- -------
data-a-1                                                 1 
data-a-2                                                 2 
data-a-3                                                 3 
data-a-4                                                 4 
data-a-5                                                 5 
data-a-6                                                 6 
data-a-7                                                 7 
data-a-8                                                 8 
data-a-9                                                 9 

  select * from b;
  SOMEDATA                                           TRACKER
-------------------------------------------------- -------
data-b--1                                                1 
data-b--2                                                2 
data-b--3                                                3 
data-b--4                                                4 
data-b--5                                                5 
data-b--6                                                6 
data-b--7                                                7 
data-b--8                                                8 
data-b--9                                                9 

  commit;


   update (select a.somedata a_somedata, b.somedata b_somedata
             from a 
                  inner join
                  b
                    on a.tracker = b.tracker)
    set 
          a_somedata = b_somedata;


select * from a;          --see below for results--

         --or you can do it this way: (issuing rollback to get data back in previous state)
         --for a one column update, either way will work, I would prefer the former in case there is a multi-column update necessary
         -- merge *as posted by another person* will also work

         update a
           set somedata = (select somedata 
                             from b
                            where a.tracker = b.tracker
                            );

          select * from A; --see below for results--

          -- clean up
          -- drop table a;
          -- drop table b;
```

this will give you the results:

```
SOMEDATA                                           TRACKER
-------------------------------------------------- -------
data-b--1                                                1 
data-b--2                                                2 
data-b--3                                                3 
data-b--4                                                4 
data-b--5                                                5 
data-b--6                                                6 
data-b--7                                                7 
data-b--8                                                8 
data-b--9                                                9
```

here is a link to oracle's documentation on [UPDATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10008.htm#SQLRF01708)